# Security of GAS for G-sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I want to create a script that runs on a Google site.  The script would perform a specialized calculation for a given user and then display the answer for the user.  The script would depend upon user input, but the code itself should not be viewable by the user.  I want the code to exist in a "black box" so that the calculation formula can be kept secret.  Is this possible?

I searched the documentation, but only found this, which does not address this question:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts

Comment: Is your site in a domain?

Comment: No.  I am thinking my answer is in the documentation, but I have not been able to find it yet.

Comment: Pages that have related info, but do not seem to answer the question:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#access_to_bound_scripts

I think the main confusion begins at me not knowing whether my script would be "bound" to Google Sites.  The documentation seems confusing to me on this subject.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script

Answer (score 1):

Whether your App script is embedded in a site or written as a standalone script does not change a lot of things... the only difference will be the way you include it on a page as a gadget.

If it is embedded it will be available from a list of scripts in the page editing, if not you'll have to use the .exec url of the deployed webapp.

Anyway, that does not change the way people will have access to the app.

You can define these parameter when you deploy the app (which is mandatory in both cases), allowing for anonymous access or requiring to be logged in.

If I understood you correctly, you would like to restrict the access to some people but not share the code.

Depending on how you defined the access mode above and wether you are using a Google Apps inside a domain or not, you will be able to do it using 2 ways :

1. in a domain you can get the logged user identity and use that to accept/deny showing the app.
2. in a "normal" gmail account you will have to implement some sort of logging feature to request a user name and password to give access to the active part of the app.

In both case **you never need to share the script** itself, this sharing parameter is independent from the webapp access.

I hope I understood your question correctly... if not, feel free to comment.

Comment: Thank you, @Serge insas !  (I have been away for a few days.)

To clarify,   I am not in a domain.  My main concern is keeping the math formulae private.  I want the math formulae to be carried out "server-side", then the answer to be passed back to the client.

...and now that you mention it, I suppose it might also be nice to restrict access to specific signed-in people, which I think I probably can do via G-site page permissions.

Comment: Looking at the "Private Functions" documentation that @living2serve posted...

"In this example, the function getBankBalance() is available in the client code; a user who inspects your source code can discover its name even if you don't call it. However, the function deepSecret_() is completely invisible to the client."

...but I am concerned about the section before, which says, "These functions cannot be called by google.script ."  Apparently I have to figure out how to call private functions...

Comment: Also, I am wondering if I misunderstand the definition of "domain".  I have a G-site, but my G-account is not a member of a university or other enterprise that uses the G-platform, so I think I do not have a "domain".  Right now I only have a personal account.  That could change if it seems worthwhile to purchase a business account.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the Private Functions section of the following page.....the example is similar to what you're referring to, I think.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=ru

I don't fully understand how they work and haven't used them myself, but I bookmarked it to figure out later.  Maybe another user who understands Private Functions better can explain...

Comment: Thank you, @living2serve ! I took a read and it seems that this could be an option.  I don't have much programming experience, so I did not even think of the term "private function".  I will search around for related info.